# aspnetcore-spa routing no provider

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, routes

I'm useing yoeman aspnetcore-spa template with angular 2.

basically, there are 3 files:

- app.module.client.ts
- app.module.server.ts
- app.module.shared.ts

I've put my Service in the providers in `app.module.client.ts` then added my routing in `app.module.shared.ts`. Which all work and great and I could navigate to it but when I try to replace `redirectTo` with my new path. Which at this point is still ok but when I enter the page from `localhost:5000` the console screams with error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeService[0] blah bla Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NameService!
```

and some `at injectionError`

if I change `redirectTo: 'home'` then it works and I could navigate to my page. What's worse is when I have `{ useHash: true }` it won't stop logging errors in the terminal.

I've tried using Router to navigate to my page in `HomeComponent` `ngOnInit()` which kind of works but still has problem when i enter the page from `localhost:5000`. What I haven't tried is replacing `HomeComponent` with mine instead.

What I really want is to understand what is going on. Honestly, I'm new to this template, normally there's just one `app.module.ts`. There is something in this template I don't understand. Please, help!

Comment: It seems like you're missing to add `NameService` in providers array of your `AppModule`

Comment: I've mentioned in my post that I've put my service in app.module.client.ts. if I didn't I wouldn't event work in the first place. 

To be clear one more time. This is the case of the service failed when the page render for the first time. When i enter from localhost:5000 with my app redirectTo my page. If i redirectTo the default home page then navigate to my page then it'll work. 

I'm sure this is something to do with dependency injection not working properly whether on my part or the framework or template.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a work around. This template does not have the usual UniversalModule, may be that's where things went wrong. I'm not sure if it's the best way to solve it but my work around is:

1. adding my service in `app.module.server.ts` as well. This is because I was thinking the home page was first rendered on the server.
2. inject ORIGIN_URL in my service. I thought I might have to do similar things to `app.module.client.ts` and it worked. So, in the constructor of my service i've added `@Inject('ORIGIN_URL') private _originUrl: string` and in my http method I prefix my url with `this._originUrl`.